# "HSH.Usuario.email: (models.E006) The field 'email' clashes with the field 'email' from model 'HSH.usuario'"

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a custom user model so that I can have three different types of user for my site.

I'm using django 2.2.1, which I have been taking a very rushed crash course on for the last few months, so admittedly I'm not very good at it quite yet, and most of my code is the result of me following other's examples on online courses or stackoverflow.

With that said, following one of these courses (speciffically coding for entrepeneur's take on custom user models), I tried to do this by inheriting the AbstractUser class and adding in the flags, and a foreign key to a different model because types of user needs to have extra info stored about them.

```
# From HSH.models.py
class Usuario(AbstractUser):

 es_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 es_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

 email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
 id_perfil = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 USERNAME_FIELD = email
```

---

```
# From settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'HSH.Usuario'
```

---

However, when I attempt to makemigrations, I get the following error message:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
HSH.Usuario.email: (models.E006) The field 'email' clashes with the field 'email' from model 'HSH.usuario'.
```

This error continues to occur even if I change the field's name.

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
HSH.Usuario.mail: (models.E006) The field 'mail' clashes with the field 'mail' from model 'HSH.usuario'.
```

What exactly is happening here? I'm completely lost at this point. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use `AbstractUser` to define `email` as `email` field already exist in the `User Model.`

You just need to add the other fields you need in extra for the `AbstractUser` class

if you need all the fields to be removed from `django's default User model` use `AbstractBaseUser` class